# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate() deep nested structure

Tags: mongoose, nested

I am building a mock customer satisfaction app. It will include a questions and answers section where the user can click a yes or no button to indicate whether an answer to a specific question was helpful or not. I am trying to write a PATCH method that can increment this yes/no property, but am having trouble with accessing the property. My data is an array of objects, each object is formatted like this:

```
    {
    "_id": "5f70eba3f66102b605e9b513",
    "question_id": 7,
    "product_id": 81,
    "created_at": "2020-09-07T15:49:10.232Z",
    "user": "Jerome_Rice12",
    "question_body": "Et aliquam ea doloribus.",
    "answers": [
        {
            "helpful": {
                "yes": 0,
                "no": 3
            },
            "_id": "5f70eba3f66102b605e9b514",
            "answer_id": 2713,
            "created_at": "2020-01-17T03:07:41.298Z",
            "body": "Est voluptatum iure necessitatibus aut et.",
            "user": "Travon.Gottlieb"
        },
        { more answer objects },
    ],
    "__v": 0
},
{ more question objects },
```

To access the yes or no property, I first have to find the relevant question id, then the correct answer id, then go in and update the answers.helpful.yes/no property. Each attempt so far has failed with postman. I have tried many different formats of the following - nothing has worked so far. Any help will be appreciated.

```
const quesId = req.params.question_id;
const ansId = req.params.answer_id;

Questions.findOneAndUpdate({
question_id: quesId, answers: { answer_id: ansId } },
  { $inc: { 'answers.$.helpful.$.no': 1 } }).exec()
.then((data) => {
  res.send(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Questions.findOneAndUpdate({
    question_id: quesId,
    'answers.answer_id': ansId
},
{
    $inc: {
        'answers.$.helpful.no': 1
    }
})
```